# undo operation for circle click in react using spread operators

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to lean react by solving a problem in react. Providing the react code challenge below. I am not seeing any error in console. But my normal click event printing.Undo operation not working. Is it good to use spread operators or do I need to use something else to improve performance

I googled but still no luck, not sure how to solve it. Providing my code below and stackblitz. Can you guys help me.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gxje5c?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css&title=React%20Starter

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';

import './style.css';

type TPoint = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState<TPoint[]>([]);

  function handlePlaceCircle(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    console.log(e);
    const { clientX, clientY } = e; // object destructuring
    setPoints([
      ...points,
      {
        x: clientX,
        y: clientY,
      },
    ]); // shallow refrence spread
  }
  function handleUndo() {
    //setPoints([...points.]);// grab only first set of elements and exclude last one
    const newPoints = [...points];
    newPoints.pop(); // this is through mutation
    setPoints(newPoints);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="circleApp" onClick={handlePlaceCircle}>
        <button onClick={handleUndo}>Undo</button>
        {points.map((point) => (
          <div
            className="point"
            style={{
              left: point.x - 5 + 'px',
              top: point.y - 5 + 'px',
            }}
          >
            o
          </div>
        ))}
        <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0BmLYHLPZs&list=PL6x5Q-Sj_Bla3_wMqhETxMBjFml0XJNPI&index=4

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for updating state seems to be working fine. The issue seems to be that your button logic is ignored because `handlePlaceCircle` is being called instead of `handleUndo`.

You could call `event.stopPropagation()` to ensure `handlePlaceCircle` isn't called when you click your button like so:

```
<button
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    handleUndo();
  }}
 >
```

Or you could simply move your button outside of your `div` which has the `handlePlaceCircle` `onClick` handler.

```
<>
  <button
    onClick={handleUndo}
  >
    Undo
  </button>
  <div className="circleApp" onClick={handlePlaceCircle}>
   {/* Other Logic... */}
  </div>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

handleUndo is fine, but the event is bubbling, so your handler for clicks is catching it. Stopping propagation will solve the issue.

```
function handleUndo(e: SyntheticEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const newPoints = [...points];
    newPoints.pop();
    setPoints(newPoints);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response...can you let me know what does bubbling means in simple terms and with respect to code

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-bubbling-in-javascript/

Basically, if you trigger an event on an element, every element above (a parent) will also get it afterwards. It's called bubbling because bubbles go up just like the event you triggered :)

Comment: So in your code, handleUndo goes first, but then its parent gets the "click event", and runs handlePlaceCircle, thus placing the new circle